# What's the difference between these .find() usages?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, find

What's the difference between

```
$data.find('select:selected');
```

and

```
$data.find('select').find(':selected');
```

?

Assume `$data = $('#data')`  ;

```
  <div id="data">
    <div>
    <select multiple>
    <option value="foo">foo</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$data.find('select').find(':selected');
```

is basically the same as

```
$data.find('select :selected');
```

Notice the [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector) (the space between `select` and `:selected`). This finds any `:selected` element that's *within* the `select` element.

Your first selector, on the other hand, finds `select:selected`, which doesn't work because [`:selected` applies to `option` elements only](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector).

Answer (score 0):

i guess the first one parse all the DOM one time and get your selector.

The second parse the dom to get your selector and parse the retrieved dom object to find the second selector

it result to the same, but performance may change between them ?